# Why facebook returns wrong start_time for some events?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm using FB api to get information about particular events. It works great but for some events it returns start_time without time zone offset. 
For example: `"start_time": "2012-09-20T16:00:00+0000"` (timezone is empty). But should be `"2012-09-20T19:00:00+0300"`
https://www.facebook.com/events/416982425024750

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, the timezone **should** be returned. However [Facebook has made some changes](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/) (as they do) with regard to time management with events. Check out what the [Events Documentation has to say](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) -

> #### Events Timezone Migration Note
>
> Starting with the 'Events Timezone' migration, all event times are
> always ISO-8601 formatted strings; the 'date_format' query string
> modifier no longer has any effect. The following formats are now
> returned, depending on the type of event:
>
> - Date-only (e.g., '2012-07-04'): events that have a date but no specific time yet.
> - Precise-time (e.g., '2012-07-04T19:00:00-0700'): events that start at a particular point in time, in a specific offset from UTC. This is
>   the way new Facebook events keep track of time, and allows users to
>   view events in different timezones.
> - Local-time (deprecated, e.g., '2012-07-04T19:00:00'): legacy events that do not have any timezone information. This format is deprecated,
>   but continues to be returned due to legacy events that are still in
>   the system.

I believe that the specific event you are talking about simply has no way to calculate the timezone offset - possibly because no location was given.

Comment: these events have the right location. For example (Ukraine, Lviv) and they also have the right format "Precise-time: 2012-07-04T19:00:00-0700" The problem is that the offset is missing. Maybe because they were created by FB Page ?

Comment: @Lix Why facebook just cant't let us request the start_time in a specific timezone is beyond me.

Comment: @ale - It's up to us to decide what timezone we want to display in. As soon as they give us the offset we have that info.

Comment: @ole - Looks like [you are not the only one](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/271562946282078) who noticed this :) I'd recommend staying posted on that bug report. Submit your recreation process to the bug and subscribe to it.  You'll receive updates when things change there...

Comment: @Lix "As soon as", being the key words here.